# Seperate UI Responsively for web and Mobile ADF Application

Tags: user-interface, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We have a adf fusion application developed in 12c,I want that application to show the components responsively in different devices. I am using Oracle Alta UI,but the problem is,it is showing the panel boxes properly but the components such as *SelectOneChoice* are not displaying responsively. May i know how can i do this? I need seperate UI based on mobile.

Comment: Can you please add some code that shows what you have already tried?

Comment: And maybe the component itself is not as responsive as you expect

Answer (score 0):

Responsiveness is something you'll need to build into your code.
You can use the af:matchmediabehavior tag to control properties of components on your page based on screen sizes.
Example:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/responsive_ui_in_oracle_adf
More samples:
https://pinboard.in/search/u:OracleADF?query=responsive